# Process Array and change date format

Tags: php, arrays, date

I asked a question earlier but realised I was asking the wrong thing.  I have an array which takes the following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10000
            [Date] => 21/11/2013
            [Total] => 10
        )
    ...
)
```

So it has an ID, Date and Total.  One issue is, I do not know what format the Date column might be, but whatever format it is I need to convert it into the format `dmy`.

So I am looping my array, I know that the key will always be Date.

```
foreach($this->csvData as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if($key === 'Date') {
            $item[$key][$value] = date("dmy", strtotime($value));
        }
    }
}
```

I am experiencing a couple of issues with the above.  Firstly, after the looping, if I output `$this->csvData`, the date values have not been converted to the new values.  I know I am in the right place because if I do this inside the if

```
print_r(date("dmy", strtotime($value));
```

I can see the altered dates.  I dont think I am reassigning them correctly though?

The other thing I am attempting to do is this.  If the date is completely wrong, say some random thing like `23455`, then I want to remove the whole element from the array.

Is this possible?  I know about validating dates, but it always seems to be validating against one particular format, whereas I do not know what the format will be.

Thanks

Comment: Reference `foreach($this->csvData as &$item)`

Comment: I get A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: You should do `$item[$key] = date("dmy", strtotime($value));` - without the extra `$value` index

Comment: You are getting this exception probably because `strtotime()` cannot convert `$value` into a time format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lay in dd/mm/yyyy format.

From `strtotime` [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So `"21/11/2013"` fail as there is no month 21...

Use `-` as `"21-11-2013"`

If you don't know the format you can check the return value of `strtotime` before:

```
$arr = [["id" => 100, "data" => "21-11-2013"]];

foreach($arr as $k => &$e) {
    $val = strtotime($e["data"]) ? strtotime($e["data"]) : strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $e["data"]));
    $e["data"] = date("m/d/y", $val);
    if (!$val) unset($arr[$k]); // if non valid date remove from array
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/MeOeY)

Comment: He said " *One issue is, I do not know what format the Date column might be* ", so I think he can't change his array as he wants.

Comment: I actually just experienced that issue.  The problem is, I do not know what format the date might be in.  This data set uses forward slashes, another might use hyphens.  Can I detect it or something/

Comment: Thanks.  That works perfectly :-) Is there any way to test if the date is completely wrong, and remove the whole element from the array?